# How do I create add a domain's configuration file to /etc/apache2/sites-available/ in Apache2?

Tags: django, apache, linode

I'm trying to point a domain (example.com) to an IP address where I have a working website built with Linode and Django. I don't want to change GoDaddy's nameservers (I purchased the domain from GoDaddy), and I was looking for example.com.conf in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/, but I could not find it. How do I get example.com.conf?

Comment: You don't want to change nameservers, what you want to do is [add an A-record](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238) which will point to your server's IP address.  Then you will need to [set up apache properly](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-18-04/) so it will look for traffic from your domain

Comment: Thank you! The site tells me how to make a new website. How do I transfer the server I have already built?

Comment: The part you're looking for is 'Step 5' on the site I linked...  Tells you what you need to put in the sites-available folder.  Just replace domain.com with your godaddy domain name and the folder structure with whatever you're using (probably pretty similar), then go through Step 6 and Step 7 of the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you so much again! The tutorial allowed me to make a blank website at my domain, but I want to move the website I already built over to the domain. How can I do that?

Comment: As noted previously, you need to add an A-record to your domain at godaddy (first link I gave in my first comment).  This A-record will point to the IP of your server, so that users who go to example.com in their browser will be shown the contents of example.com.  This also requires that your server is properly configured to receive traffic looking for example.com, which is what the link I sent enables you to do.  So you need both those parts working together to make the whole thing function properly.  Doesn't matter if it's a new site or a current site.

Comment: Another note: there is no 'move the site to my domain'.  Your domain is just something that points people to where your files are actually being stored (your web host/server).  A domain cannot host a website because it is not a website host (although domain providers often also offer hosting solutions).

Comment: Thank you again! I've already added the A-record before, but when I go to example.com it still gives me the "testing for example.com" screen. Any idea where the issue might be coming from? I really want to thank you so much by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220239/discussion-between-cccompro-and-kaboodleschmitt).